# How do I POST JSON data using jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

I've recently been given a project, the instructions are as follows:

> Create an HTML page that will make a call to our API endpoint to
> retrieve a list of logs on our API logger, load the data into a
> visually pleasing grid. The page should make this call every minute,
> and up existing rows with new data via AJAX (partial page update, the
> entire page should not reload). If the row no longer exist in the new
> data, remove the row. If new data does not exist in any of the rows,
> add a new row with the data.
>
> The API call is to be made using the `POST` method with jQuery AJAX
> snippets to our API endpoint, with the following JSON Request object:
>
> ```
> {
>  "token": "CyvW1tW7hBMGNvSY752xr4QbK1TStbxhy8xSGfpMm1JxlSwjn7fXWU2LD7tVoP5przifFd0TnAHMJxf0maAvyAGN90FHfWk76IhO"
> }
> ```
>
> The JSON Response object from the server should look something like
> this:
>
> ```
> {
>  "logs": [
>  {
>  "Description": string,
>  "ApplicationName": string,
>  "Client_IP": string,
>  "Server_IP": string,
>  "RequestEndPoint": string,
>  "LastOccurrence": datetime string,
>  "ResponseCode": integer,
>  "Last24HourLogCount": integer
>  },
>  ]
> }
> ```

I'm having trouble with the `POST` request and gathering the JSON data. When I make an API test call using Postman I'm able to receive the JSON data, but not when I make the calls through my HTML page, below are my attempts:

### Attempt 1

Here I created a `POST` request to the endpoint and attempt to convert the JSON data into a string to be displayed within an alert:

I got the following alert popup:

[image]

This is the message in the console:

[image]

If I remove the token header and add the JSON data from Postman to my variable I get this console error instead:

[image]

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://fetch1.hipposhq.com/hipposapilogstatus",
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    headers:{
         "token": "CyvW1tW7hBMGNvSY752xr4QbK1TStbxhy8xSGfpMm1JxlSwjn7fXWU2LD7tVoP5przifFd0TnAHMJxf0maAvyAGN90FHfWk76IhO"
    },
    success: function(data){alert(JSON.stringify(data))},
    error: function(errMsg) {
         alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

### Attempt 2

Here I created a `POST` request to the endpoint and attempt to display the JSON data in the console log, I receive an error instead:

This is the message in the console:

[image]

If I remove the token header and add the JSON data from Postman to my variable I get the same error:

[image]

```
var data = {}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://fetch1.hipposhq.com/hipposapilogstatus",
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    headers:{
        "token": "CyvW1tW7hBMGNvSY752xr4QbK1TStbxhy8xSGfpMm1JxlSwjn7fXWU2LD7tVoP5przifFd0TnAHMJxf0maAvyAGN90FHfWk76IhO"
    },             
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

### Attempt 3

Here I created a `POST` request with the JSON data I received from Postman (actual data omitted) to receive the JSON data and display it in the console log, I receive an error instead:

This is the error in the console:

[image]

When I add the token header I receive the same access and resource errors:

[image]

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"https://fetch1.hipposhq.com/hipposapilogstatus",
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
            "logs": [
                {
                "Description": "string",
                "ApplicationName": "string",
                "Client_IP": "string",
                "Server_IP": "string",
                "RequestEndPoint": "string",
                "LastOccurrence": "datetime string",
                "ResponseCode": integer,
                "Last24HourLogCount": integer,
                },
            ]
        }),
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I want to be able to receive the JSON data in the console as a string/object/array so I can display it on my page, but I'm unsure of where to go from here.

Comment: as an aside -> `dataType:'json',` wont' fix the CORS issue, but this is the correct format

Comment: I will correct this format issue, thanks. @Kinglish

Comment: Maybe if someone could help me solve this lmaoo. But in all seriousness I'm a bit intimidated asking my first question here so I wanted to clarify and ask for patience. @freedomn-m

Comment: No worries, just always find it funny - the expression is *"please bear with me"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had to send the token as data

```js
const $output = $("#logs");
const process = response => $output.html(
    response.logs.map(log =>  `<hr/><dl>${
      Object.entries(log).map(([key,val]) => `<dt>${key}</dt><dd>${val}</dd>`).join("")
    }</dl>`).join(""));

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://fetch1.hipposhq.com/hipposapilogstatus",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    "token": "CyvW1tW7hBMGNvSY752xr4QbK1TStbxhy8xSGfpMm1JxlSwjn7fXWU2LD7tVoP5przifFd0TnAHMJxf0maAvyAGN90FHfWk76IhO"
  },
  success: process,
  error: function(request, status, error) {
    console.log(request.responseText);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="logs"><div>
```

Comment: The answer was right there, but I was really struggling evidently lol, I will accept this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```js
var data = {
  "logs": [{
    "Description": 'string',
    "ApplicationName": 'string',
    "Client_IP": 'string',
    "Server_IP": 'string',
    "RequestEndPoint": 'string',
    "LastOccurrence": 'datetime string',
    "ResponseCode": 'integer',
    "Last24HourLogCount": 'integer'
  }, ]
}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://fetch1.hipposhq.com/hipposapilogstatus",
  data: data,
  dataType: 'JSON',
  headers: {
    "token": "CyvW1tW7hBMGNvSY752xr4QbK1TStbxhy8xSGfpMm1JxlSwjn7fXWU2LD7tVoP5przifFd0TnAHMJxf0maAvyAGN90FHfWk76IhO"
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please add details explaining how your code helps to answer the question.   For example, why are you sending the *expected response* as the request?

Comment: Well in attempt 3 OP is doing just that

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the CORS issue, besides being nearly identical to OPs attempt